# use 'case when' after in function

Tags: sql, db2

I need to use **case when** to generate the value range for in function (in DB2).
for example, in below code, I want the columnB in (5,6)

```
 select columnA from tableName where columnB in (
    (case 
    when @variable=1 then '4' // specific number
    when @variable=2 then '5'  //specific number
    when @variable=3 then '7,10'  // a value range
    end)
 )
```

but tried several times and other similar solutions, never got the expected result

how to do this?

Comment: why case? also 1 = 1 is always true. Please explain what you are trying to do

Comment: tks for ur reply, improved my Qu

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `In` function does not read multiple values inside `Case` statement. The comma must be after every single value in the range.

Second, you can mention a valid condition in your Question, rather than just `1=1`. It's always true so, doesn't make sense.

Example:
1) output of below query gives `in (5, 6)`

```
select columnA from tableName where columnB in ((case when @variable=1 then 5 end), 6);
```

2) this gives only records of columnB = 5, let say the second condition is `false`.

```
select columnA from tableName where columnB in ((case when @variable=1 then 5 end), (case when @variable=2 then 6 end));
```

Comment: @SamualLee, certainly, this is the way to use cases inside `IN` function.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this

```
select columnA from tableName 
where columnB  in (                         
    select * from table(values 4) tmp(NewCol)    
    where @variable=1
    union all
    select * from table(values 5) tmp(NewCol)    
    where @variable=2 
    union all
    select * from table(values 7, 10) tmp(NewCol)    
    where @variable=3                                      
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have string as value range unless you convert it into rowset. I'm not sure how to do this in DB2, but I have something that should work, since according to documentation, DB2 does have unnest(). There are of course other ways to create rowsets.

```
SELECT columnA
  FROM unnest(array[2,6,8,10], array[7,5,6,28]) --create "temp table" for example purposes
  WITH ORDINALITY AS a(columnA, columnB) --alias columns from temp table
 WHERE
   CASE WHEN true THEN --switch true to some other condition
     columnB IN(SELECT * FROM unnest(array[5,6])) --unnest(array[]) will create rowset with 2 rows, each having one column holding integer value
   END;
```

You might need to drop alias from `AS a(columnA, columnB)` since I'm not sure if it works in DB2 and I have not found live DB2 tester (it is required in PostgreSQL where I tested query).